# "Question eligible for bounty in 2 days". Why?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've just posted a question and a few moments later, this message was displayed below it. I read about bounty and I understood what it means and my question is pretty specific. But why is it marked as "eligible for bounty" without any consent of my part?

Comment: I think it's just supposed to be a placeholder for the actual bounty link, so more people know about it.

Comment: Perhaps the message should rather say something like "you can add a bounty to this question in 2 days". I think that would be less confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bounties can be offered by any user with sufficient rep on any question; consent is never involved.  The only other condition is that the question isn't new.  New questions don't need to be bountied, since they already show up in the New tab and the Active tab and so on (and thus get attention anyways).

Comment: Being that the case, it's not my reputation rather than the user's who deemed it eligible for bounty that is... "at stake", in the lack of a better term?

Comment: @S.O. Correct. That message is just there so you discover the concept of bounties.